# Начало работы IOS App (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Не могу открыть файл .storyboard для редактирования пользовательского интерфейса в Visual Studio на винде. Во всех инструкциях скокойно открывается  iOS Designer,а у меня просто файл с кодом. Мак подключен